# Why show the number of comment edits without the edit history?

Tags: support, edits, comments

Why does the pencil icon's tooltip show the number of comment edits? Why not show the comment's history then?

If the edit history is shown, we'd get to see the number of edits as well as what was changed in edit 1, edit 2, etc.

[image]

Comment: official test comment

Comment: official test comment 1.

Answer (score 2):

I'd think that edit history isn't listed because that would mean also <del>storing and</del> maintaining all edits all the time.

<del>Just having a 'how many edits' means storing a single number for every comment, but not an nth number of extra columns or rows for the changes.</del>

It would <del>save storage size needed to host SO, and would</del> reduce the amount of bandwidth needed to display the pages since the data will literally never be used <del>if it no longer exists</del>.

Maybe they're relying on the person editing to actually be committing to his/her edit as thought they actually do intend to change the comment...?

To continue and respond to why have the number without the history.

1. It doesn't take up nearly as much room.
2. It shows viewers that the comment has changed and previous information or counter comments may have been made on \given against different information.
3. Novelty factor for the developers?
4. Perhaps there is a history for security reasons... perhaps the number of changes is datestamped each time a change occurs to show usage patterns of the website?
5. Or perhaps a high comment change count just shows that the person making that comment cannot make their mind up or contribute a concise succinct contribution that they can stick to?

### Edit:

As pointed out in comments by 'Normal Human', the changes are stored each and everytime.

With that in mind my points regarding storage are void, but bandwidth and maintaining are still somewhat relevant.
It seems that the data is retained but not output for us, be it due to extra overhead in terms of coding time, maintaining, aesthetics, or bandwidth.

Comment: AFAIAC That number can go.

Comment: Nice assumption..

Comment: All edits __are__ stored. [Anna Lear wrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240827/do-moderators-see-the-previous-versions-of-edited-comments#comment789554_240828): "while there is no user/moderator UI for it, we do keep comment history and can look it up if needed."